# How do I get next week number in Bash?

Tags: bash, date, week-number

I simply like to get the next week number of the year using `Bash`. I have a working script as follows but I am not pretty sure if it is the right way to do so. I have a concern specially around what it produces if the week is `52`? Would output be `53` or `1`?

```
echo $(($(date +%-V)+1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the next week number use:

```sh
nweek=$(date -d '+1 week' '+%-V')
echo $nweek

49
```

Adding `1` to current week number will give wrong result of `53` for the last week of the year.

On the other hand, above command will give `1` for the same case because we are adding `1 week` in the current date and then getting week number.

Comment: Note that `%V` is [ISO week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week) number (starting at week 1 for the first week containing the 4th of January, with week starting at Monday).